# Can't turn off real-time protection

Tags: windows-10

Trying to turn off real-time protection on my Windows 10 connected to MS account, but found message

```
"This setting is managed by your administrator"
```

[image]
Deleting registry below not helped:
REG DELETE "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender" /v DisableAntiSpyware

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Is this PC your own or is it managed in any way (Active Directoy, Azure AD, Intune)? Please note that your account type (Microsoft or not) has no relation to this.

Comment: PC is not managed in any way

Comment: Do you have other third party Anti Virus installed?

Comment: No, there is no third party Anti Virus

Comment: Then I think Windows Defender will remain on. Microsoft insist on Anti Virus protection on user machines.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will not be able to disable the slider if you use Windows 10 Home.

That said, if you install any third-party AV, Windows will automatically disable the antivirus. You can then manage the third-party AV and disable its protection temporarily.

Comment: Correct - you cannot turn off Real Time on Home

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings, Security, Virus & threat protection, Manage settings, Tamper
protection. Set to Off. Then add this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Real-Time Protection]
"DisableRealtimeMonitoring"=dword:00000001
```